# overlaying xarray data with shapefile using

Tags: python, xarray

```
import xarray
import xshape
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

da.xshape.overlay(shapefile,colors=['b', 'orange', 'g', 'r', 'c', 'm', 'y', 'grey', 'Brown', 'ForestGreen'],levels =10)
```

[image: India clusters]

I tried to plot xarray data with boundaries by shape files using xshape . I am geting connected lines over sea for india